# View display content by value based on user profile field values

Tags: views

I need to create a view that displays saved content with defined field values to users with specific attributes.   I.E.

content form with a field boolean of regulated:
  [0] unregulated
  [1] regulated
  [2] both

the view needs to display this content depending upon the user profile value for whether that user is licensed or not.  field value of both needs to display regardless of profile value for licensed.

profile field licensed is a boolean.  0 non-licensed, 1 licensed.

There will be content marked as regulated that needs only to be displayed to licensed users, content that is not regulated that needs only to be displayed to non licensed users, and content that is marked for both that needs to be displayed to both licensed and non-licensed users.

Can this be done in views or do I need to write custom php to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

You may use the [flag](https://www.drupal.org/project/flag) module to flag users (*it could be an automatic flagging in conjunction with [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules)*)as regulated, unregulated or both and then filter via views all flagged users. For anonymous users needs some  [special](https://www.drupal.org/node/999102) handling.

Comment: I've looked at the flag module and don't think that's what I'm going for.  There are no anonymous users on this system other than viewing the landing page and a couple of other basic pages.

Comment: I can't describe the whole procedure you have to follow in order to accomplish your feature (lack of time),but  don't underestimate the flag module, have a look here[link] (http://jan.tomka.name/blog/list-recently-viewed-nodes-drupal)[link], it may change your mind. It's up to you

Comment: I'm looking into these two modules as possible solutions.
[views_conditional][1]
[rules_conditional][2]

[1]: https://www.drupal.org/projects/views_conditional
[2]: https://www.drupal.org/projects/rules_conditional